# Replace The Integer Values Of Dataframe With blanks

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a dataframe with float64 dtypes columns and i want to replace the integer values with blanks and leave intact .

I tried several ways to do it but none of them worked.

Some examples of what i tried are:

```
for cols in df.columns:
   df[cols]=df[cols].mask(df[cols].is_integer(),' ')
```

2nd way:

```
for cols in df.columns:
   df[df[col]%1==0] =' '
```

Can you please advise on the above?

I also thought of something like the below:

```
for cols in df.columns:

   if df[cols].contains("."):
      df[cols].replace(
```

but i dont think of what to enclose in the brackets .

Comment: Can you show on your question what your dataframe looks like? You're more likely to get an answer if you give a mock example of what your data looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this approach using [`df.applymap()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html)?

```py
df = df.applymap(lambda x: " " if x.is_integer() else x)
```

**Demo:** You can run code [**Here**](https://www.online-python.com/)

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [34.7, 57.0, 33.1], "col2": [774.0, 4.5, 11.0]})

df = df.applymap(lambda x: " " if x.is_integer() else x)
print(df)
```

---

```
   col1 col2
0  34.7     
1        4.5
2  33.1
```

Comment: That worked just fine mate! Thank you very much for your immediate response!